# get average of subtotal and wet with respect to distinct purchaseorderid and product category in DAX

Tags: sql, excel, powerbi, dax

i don't know where to start, pretty new in power bi or Dax
here is sample data

```
  PurchaseOrderId    SubTotal    Wet         ProductCategory   
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1021               804.9767    233.4432    Wine              
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1022               228.4651    66.2548     Beer              
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1022               228.4651    66.2548     RTD               
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1022               228.4651    66.2548     Wine              
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1023               2791.2558   809.4641    Wine              
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1023               2791.2558   809.4641    Beer              
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1023               2791.2558   809.4641    Non-alcoholic     
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1023               2791.2558   809.4641    RTD               
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1024               396         114.84      Wine              
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1025               374.2325    108.5274    Wine              
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1026               864.093     250.5869    Wine              
 ------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------------ 
  1027               127.9069    37.093      Wine
```

what i want is i want average order value i.e
(Subtotal+Wet)/Count(Distinct PurchaseOrderId).

For this table Sum of distinct Subtotal is 5586.93 and Sum of
distinct wet is 1620.20,
total number of distinct purchaseorderid i.e number of orders is 7 so my average order value is (5586.93+1620.20)/7 = 1029.59,
i also want average order value by category
i am doing everything in DAX
so how this can be achieved?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could start by: (1) posting copiable data, as opposed to a picture; (2) including the expected results for the given data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this measure: I called my table (Test00) You can use yours in the same way.

```
AverageOfSubTotal = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE (Test00, Test00[PurchaseOrderId], Test00[ProductCategory]),
    "Total_SubTotal",CALCULATE(SUM(Test00[SubTotal]))
)
RETURN
    AVERAGEX(TblSummary,[Total_SubTotal])
```

If we test it on a table visual:

[image: REsult]

Now let's test the visual table report performance on DAX Studio:

[image: Test Report]

The results are quite good!! 5 ms query time (4ms FE, 1 ms SE). 4 SE(Storage Engine) queries.

Comment: will it consider purchaseid as distinct

Comment: It will consider all possible unique combinations of (purchased + product category ).

Comment: thanks, what if i have to add two columns wet+subtotal and divide it by # of orders? how this can be achieved? i mean this is how average would be calculated for me, without the use of Averagex

Comment: You can do it; but why you should do it if performance sucks? I think AVERAGEX() version will perform better. Less query time, and less number of storage engine queries.

Comment: Hey Ozan, Thanks for the efforts put it in here, i have edited the question, could you please read and guide me? Thanks

Comment: No. My job is finished here. You will solve the problem, and learn it better.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a new **Measure**

```
Avg Subtotal = 
AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[PurchaseOrderId],
        'Table'[ProductCategory],
        'Table'[SubTotal]
    ),
    'Table'[SubTotal]
)
```

Comment: thanks peter, what if i have to add two columns (wet+subtotal) and divide it by (# of orders)? how this can be achieved? i mean this is how average would be calculated for me, without the use of Averagex

Comment: We need the X-funtions AverageX() basically to iterate over the temporary grouped table that is build via SUMARIZE(). Instead of this you could just use this calculated table and add another column with the 2 parameters `"Count", COUNT('Table'[SubTotal])` and then do your math on that new grouped table.

Comment: It would have been easier for you to understand and judge the answer if you had provided both your expected solution and a your sample data (in copyable text format), like recommended by StackOverflow. Now it looks like a waste of time for everyone.

Comment: Hey peter i have edited the question, please look at the data and expected result

Comment: Looks like you don't value voluntary help.

Comment: No i do, i would like to thank you